# Struggling to plot multiple columns against x using Pandas dataframe from .txt file

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to plot several graphs on the same plot using a pandas dataframe, but I'm getting an error probably because I'm not doing it properly and I can't figure it out. Below is a screenshot of my code (sorry the code formatter tool isn't working):
[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3ce2.png)

And I keep getting ''ValueError: x and y must be the same size''. Just for reference here is the data I am trying to plot, with the R column on the x axis and the specified columns on the x axis: [Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVPpS.png)

Comment: IHMO, scatter only accept one `x` and one `y` at a time. Also, you don't need to do `SAPT_data=pd.DataFrame(SAPT_data)`: `pd.read_csv` returns a DataFrame already.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried :

```
for column in ['exch', 'IND2', 'elst', 'dHf', 'DISP2'] :
    SAPT_DATA.plot(x="R", y=column, kind="scatter")
```

It should solve your problem since scatter only takes one column for the 'y' argument

EDIT :

If you want to have everything in one plot, with lines between points and special markers, you can use the following arguments for the `plot` function :

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for column in ['exch', 'IND2', 'elst', 'dHf', 'DISP2'] :
    SAPT_DATA.plot(x="R", y=column, style='o-', ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried this out and it gave me the plots but it gave me them separately whereas I want them all on the same graph. Also, do you know how I can make all the points in the scatter joined up with a line like how it's done in matplotlib?

Comment: If you want a line between them you shouldn't use the `scatter` argument. Instead, draw a regular plot and add markers on each points by using the following code :
`fig, ax = plt.subplots()` then `SAPT_DATA.plot(x='R', y=column, style='o-', ax=ax)`

Answer (score 0):

You can only do one value in the y because it's a scatter plot. Intead, you should melt your data frame (`df.melt(...)`) using "R" as the `id_var` and the other 5 columns as your `value_vars` and then use seaborn or altair to plot these:

```
import seaborn as sns
df = df.melt(id_var='R',
             value_vars=['exch', 'IND2', 'elst', 'dHF', 'DISP2'],
             var_name='energy_type',
             value_name='energy')
sns.relplot(data=df, x='R', y='energy', hue='energy_type')
```

Side note: you are making a dataframe out of a dataframe in your code, but that doesn't cause an error; just something redundant to eliminate.

Comment: Amazing, thanks! I tried this out and it gave me it all on one graph which is what I wanted however I have a few issues (I have posted my graph below as an answer since I can't include images in comments):
1) I assumed 'variable' was free to edit to make whatever variable it is that these points represent, in my case it's energies, but when I changed it to 'energies' it didn't let me.
2) Is there any way I can join the points up with curves going through each of them like in matplotlib line plots?

Comment: Yes that can be done using the `var_name` and `value_name` arguments in the `melt` method (I have edited it to reflect that now).

Answer (score 0):

Update: [Graph using teepee's method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3CEo.png)